# Search XML node values with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml

I need to search XML node value with PHP. here is my XML data.

```
 <catalog> 
 <book id="bk100">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developers Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications
      with XML.</description>
   </book>  
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>author, kumar</author>
      <title>PHP Developers Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>50.25</price>
      <publish_date>2015-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>PHP Applications</description>
   </book> 
   </catalog>
```

I am using below PHP code for fetching the values in webpage.

```
<?php
    // Loading the XML file
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("data.xml");
    echo "<h2>".$xml->getName()."</h2><br />";

    foreach($xml->children() as $book)
    {
        echo "BOOK : ".$book->attributes()->id."<br />";
        echo "Author : ".$book->author." <br />";
        echo "Title : ".$book->title." <br />";
        echo "Genre : ".$book->genre." <br />";
        echo "Price : ".$book->price." <br />";
        echo "Publish Date : ".$book->publish_date." <br />";
        echo "Description : ".$book->description." <br />";
        echo "<hr/>";
    }
?>
```

It will return complete list of data's in XML. I need to search a particular word in XML and need to show that particular node only. For ex. If i am searching the keyword `PHP`. It will return the second node only. and also i need search in a particular attribute like `publish_date` and also i need order the XML data by DESC or ASC by particular fields.

I have More than 1 million records in XML format, so is there any dependencies to filtering and showing the data. and also i need to show is there any possibility to show this using jquery and Ajax.

Comment: you could use `$xml->xpath()` for this also if you want to search

Comment: *I have More than 1 million records in XML format* - do you want to sort this array? does simplexml load such file ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommand you to use XPath to make some queries.

Check this out : http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: This example shows the XML data is in variable. but i am calling XML data from external files. So i don't know where i can change it from external data

Comment: `simplexml_load_file()` load the XML to your variable, you can use XPath easily. There is a lot of example.